# Show node connection in different time in python

Tags: python

Suppose I want to model a network of individuals which people are in contact with each other at different time. Also, I'm using python for modelling. is it possible to plot something like this figure in python? actually, I need something like the picture (a).
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to keep track of different locale date stamps is to use UTC time in milliseconds and adjust dynamic the offset each person has.

Scenario:
You are asking from your local computer (local time):
Give me all the contacts made today at 10:00

In order for the above to work it must be structured like this:

- Every time a user has a contact, store its datetime stamp in UTC
  format (milliseconds), along with the timezone offset (-120 min).
- When it comes to retrieve contacts information in specific datetime, remove
  the offset in order to correct the datetime in your timezone.

Keep in mind, time represented in linear way no matter the structure of the network. Then you can form any logic behind your case.

i hope to pin point a new approach to your problem!

**UPDATE** REFERENCE LINKS FOR APPROACH:

1. [Network Plot Theory](https://www.networkpages.nl/graph-theory/)
2. [An excellent example by @Mikewise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44173126/python-friends-network-visualization)

Comment: actually, I don't know how to plot it. with which package or how is the code

Comment: @Zahra check both links above! :)